# И "домы", и "дома" у Гончарова

Tags: выбор-слов

В "Обыкновенной истории" Гончарова в одном абзаце встречаются и "домы", и "дома":

> Он посмотрел на ***домы*** – и ему стало ещё скучнее: на него наводили тоску эти однообразные каменные громады, которые, как колоссальные гробницы, сплошною массою тянутся одна за другою. «Вот кончается улица, сейчас будет приволье глазам, – думал он, – или горка, или зелень, или развалившийся забор», – нет, опять начинается та же каменная ограда одинаких домов, с четырьмя рядами окон. И эта улица кончилась, её преграждает опять то же, а там новый порядок таких же домов. Заглянешь направо, налево – всюду обступили вас, как рать исполинов, ***дома, дома и дома,*** камень и камень, всё одно да одно… нет простора и выхода взгляду: заперты со всех сторон, – кажется, и мысли и чувства людские также заперты.

Почему так? Ошибка вкралась в современный текст, а у него было одинаково? Вряд ли. Если нет, то может между этими вариантами есть нюанс различия? Или же он неумышленно так написал при отсутствии строгой нормы? Тоже навряд ли.

Comment: Уч**и**тели - учител**я**.  Проф**е**ссоры - профессор**а**, Дом**ы** - дом**а**.  Строгой нормы нет, пишешь, что взбредёт.

Comment: А почему Вы уверены, что именно "дом**ы**", а не "д**о**мы"? У меня как раз второй вопрос про это.

Comment: Я не уверен, Артём.  Я просто проводил аналогию (в другом коментарии) с дымы и холмы.  Ударение в русском (у Славы в ответе примеры - из поэзии), достаточно вольная штука.  Наверняка можно найти случаи с ударением в "дымы" на первую "ы", и в "холмы" - на "о"...

Comment: Насчёт холмов вспомнил, что по ц.-славянски как раз "х**о**лми".

Comment: Вчера слушал Германа Ильича Энтина в театре Ермоловой, так он сказал: "на Кузнецком м**о**сте". Это он Булгакова читал.

Comment: Ну, это просто нарушение всех правил ;-)...  Это ведь "местный" падеж!

Comment: Не буду утверждать, вдруг я ослышался или не так запомнил, а то ещё его скомпрометирую. :(

Comment: Наверно, всё-таки там было "по Кузнецкому м**о**сту". А он всё говорит очень правильно, так что и тут это явно неспроста должно быть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В "Обыкновенной истории" Гончарова в одном абзаце встречаются и
>   "домы", и "дома"...

***Домы***  (с ударением на ***"о"***) -- старая норма; Во времена Гончарова говорили и ***домы***, и ***дома***.

[**Из словаря Ушакова**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/792650):

> **ДОМ**, дома, из дому и из дома, **мн.** дома (**до̀мы** *устар.*)

Что же до встречи в одном и том же тексте у Гончарова форм и ***домы*** и ***дома***… Вполне возможно, что в **им. падеже** он отдавал предпочтение одной форме (***дома***), **в винительном** -- другой: ***(на) домы***.

===

Форма ***домы*** встречается и у поэтов ХХ века. См. примеры из Нацкорпуса:

*Слух чудо̀вищный бро̀дит по го̀роду, Забира̀ется **в до̀мы**, как та̀ть.*
 [**А. А. Ахматова**. «Слух чудовищный бродит по городу...» (1922)]

*Врата̀ без затво̀ра ―
Сон. **До̀мы** ― без вра̀т.
Все́ ― тѐни, все́ ― во̀ры...*
[**М. И. Цветаева**. Сны [Крысолов, 2] (1925)]

*Ѝ ключѝ звеня̀т, как шпо̀ры,
Кто̀ их слы̀шит? **До̀мы** спя̀т.*
[**Д. Самойлов**. «Что сказать официанткам...» (1973)]