# Ударения в словах до революции

Tags: орфоэпия

1. В слове "домы" ударение падало на О, правильно?
2. Правда ли, что в слове "музыка" ударение было на Ы, или верно утверждение, что так поставил ударение только в одном стихотворении Пушкин, а все говорили, как и сейчас, "м**у**зыка"?
3. Где-то прочитал, что в слове "библиотека" ударение было на О. Это чушь собачья или правда?

Comment: Думаю, что в слове домы ударение было на "ы".  Как дымы, как холмы.

Comment: Где-то я видел как раз д**о**мы. Хотя до этого думал, что дом**ы**, как в белорусском звучит.

Comment: Кстати, музыка у Даля 1880г имеет ударение как на у, так и на ы.

Comment: Интересно!********

Comment: Посмотрел у Даля 1880г - библи*о*т**е**ка (основное ударение на е, слабее - на о), так что можно было говорить *библи**о**тека*, наверное.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В слове "домы" ударение падало на О, правильно?

[Правильно.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419220/%D0%98-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%83-%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

> Правда ли, что в слове "музыка" ударение было на Ы, или верно
>   утверждение, что **так поставил ударение только в одном стихотворении
>   Пушкин**, а все говорили, как и сейчас, "музыка"?

Не только **Пушкин** (кстати, у него [не в одном стихотворении](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=%28metas%253A%2522author%2522%2520%2526%2520%28!%25EF%25F3%25F8%25EA%25E8%25ED%29%29&mysent=&mysize=209225&mysentsize=19730&mydocsize=957&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=poetic&sort=gr_tagging&ext=10&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EC%F3%E7%FB%EA%E0&gramm1=&flags1=&sem1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&flags2=&sem2=) такое ударение).

**Из Нацкорпуса**:

*Я слы̀шу та̀м, как здѐсь, прия̀тную̀ **музы̀ку**; 
Там о̀т усѐрдного̀ наро̀дов ра̀зных клѝку…* [**М. В. Ломоносов.** Надпись к ее величеству государыне императрице Елисавете Петровне на маскарады 1751 года (1750-1751)]

*Гремѝт **музы̀ка**, слы̀шны хо̀ры
Вкруг ла̀комы̀х твоѝх столо̀в…* [**Г. Р. Державин.** К первому соседу (1780)]

> Где-то прочитал, что в слове "библиотека" ударение было на О. Это чушь
>   собачья или правда?

Насколько распространённым было такое ударение -- не знаю. Но словарём Ушакова фиксировалось:

**БИБЛИО́ТЕ́КА** (проверил по бумажному словарю).